# How to get value of style attribute from a code behind property?

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2013

In my .aspx I have this :

```
 <style type="text/css">
       .item .item_background .item_general_info .button_wrapper .add_button {

           background-color: /* MyProp from code behind */
       }

   </style>
```

On the code behind :

```
public String MyProp 
{
  get {return DB.GetColor();}
}
```

How can I set the value of the background-color dynamically from the code behind ?

Thanks

Comment: do you have a server control for the property you want to get the attribute from ?

Comment: @ Veverke : No, it's not runat server

Answer (score 1):

If this is a aspx, you can try to define that member on the class as a protected member:

`protected string _myServerColor;`

Then assign that prop when the page loads:

`protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
         _myServerColor = "#FFF"; // assign this to your db color
}`

And then, as long as your style tag is within the same page, you could do:

```
<style type="text/css">
       .item .item_background .item_general_info .button_wrapper .add_button {

           background-color: "<%= _myServerColor %>";
       }

   </style>
```

Cleanest way would be to make this controls `runat="server"` so you could assign properties from the backend directly.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can add a style attribute to your CSS style class from code-behind this way:

```
Style style1 = new Style();
style1.BackColor = Color.Orange; // Insert the desired color here
Header.StyleSheet.CreateStyleRule(style1, null, ".item .item_background .item_general_info .button_wrapper .add_button");
```

In order for that to work, the `head` section of the page must have the `runat="server"` attribute:

```
<head runat="server">
    <style type="text/css">
        .item .item_background .item_general_info .button_wrapper .add_button 
        {
            ...
        }
    </style>
    ...
</head>
```